# How to install Windows on a MacBook without Bootcamp parallely?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install, windows

Recently my Mac got erased while trying to format the partiton. So i was trying to install windows 8.1 on my MacBook Pro. I can't use Bootcamp as there is no OS X in my Mac. The Internet Recovery is taking very long to recover so I would like to shorten the process and install Windows 8 parallely. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you saying that you only what to install and run Windows on the MacBook Pro and not install/reinstall OS X at all?

Comment: I would have to guess. So would anyone else. I need to know your model identifier or at least the screen size/model year. For example, my model identifier is iMac7,1 and screen size/model year  is 20 inch/mid 2007. One has to consider BIOS vs GPT install and DVD vs USB installs. Also, whether Apple supports 8.1 for your Mac or not. (Most of the time you can install even if Apple does not support your model). Also, do you have any other machines running OS X or Windows? If another Mac, do you have a firewire cable. If your post a comment, be sure to include a @David so I will be notified.

Comment: This guide is for those of you who have tried every solution – and upon reading the numerous forums which conclude that Windows “can only be installed via Bootcamp” – have given up. This guide illustrates the exact same steps I used to install Windows on my MacBook Pro without using Boot Camp. http://daksh.me/how-to-install-windows-on-your-mac-without-bootcamp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The First Answer given by [Steve Chambers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/33273/steve-chambers) is actually right.But in my case the answer would be try to get some backup from other mac and backup the os from `Time Machine` so that you can install `OSX` with the backup faster and you just have to format the drive.And after that partition the harddisk and use a `Win 8.1` DVD to boot (press and hold the alt button when booting up the macbook).And this will install Win 8.1 in Mac without `BootCamp`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you will need to download Bootcamp from Apple as all the drivers are there. I've never tried to download it on a PC but it should be possible to open the BootCamp.app package on a PC (it's just a folder) and get to the drivers that way.

But if you have Windows 8.1 bootable install media you should be able to boot your Mac from it, format and select a partition and install Windows. **Generally** Windows will work on a Mac without the Boot Camp drivers. Depending on your model some parts will not work, so I would download the bootcamp installer and put it on the same media as the Windows installer so you don't have to download it on a Mac running Windows without a working NIC.

It would be helpful, to know the model of Mac you have and what your experiences are doing this. What works and does not, what you had to work around to get it up and running.